# NSJSONSerialization adding \n to beginning and end of JSON string

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, nsjsonserialization

I have an iOS application that needs to post some information to the server in json format. In particular, I need to pick up an NSArray of Strings and convert it into a NSString in json format. I am using the following code to create the string:

```
NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:_selectedStyles options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&error];
    if(error){
        //TODO: handle error
    }
NSString *selectedStylesInJson = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

However, the string that comes out of that is the following:

```
@"[\n  \"schlager\",\n  \"volkstuemlicherSchlager\"\n]"
```

As you can see, the NSJSONSerialization method is inserting a \n before and after every string in the array, which is incorrect.

How can I make iOS convert this array in the correct format? The format I am looking for is:

```
["object 1", "object 2"]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the output is absolutely correct. It is fine to add spaces and newlines in JSON in the right places. And JSON parser will be able to parse it.

Why does it happen? Because you were absolutely careless in your cde. Look at the option that you pass. It is an option that is used when you parse JSON, not when you write JSON. Why are you passing an option for reading JSON to a method that writes JSON? Now go and look at the writing options, and look which writing option has exactly the same value as the reading option that you passed.

Comment: The following code produces the desired output:     NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:_selectedStyles options:nil error:&error];

PS: you can be helpful without being rude. Thanks for the pointer.

Answer (score 2):

Use 
`[NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:self options:0 error:nil];
[NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:self options:kNilOptions 
 error:nil];`

> If that option is not set, the most compact possible JSON will be generated. If an error occurs, the error parameter will be set and the return value will be nil. The resulting data is a encoded in UTF-8.

Come from Apple Document.